# getting the type of a types properties

Tags: typescript, types

I currently have a type pulled from a third party. i'd like to get the type of a property of that type. for typescript.

e.g.

```
type GivenType = {
    prop: string;
}

type desiredType = <<getTypeOf GivenType.prop>>

desiredType === string // true;
```

I'm looking for the actual syntax for `<<getTypeOf GivenType.prop>>`

mostly I've looked through the typescript documentation and found that extracting type is generally acted on objects or interfaces. such commands like `typeof` or `returnType`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the type of a property like this:

```
type SomePropertyType = SomeType["SomeProperty"];
```

This is an "indexed access operator"; there are details in [this documentation section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types).

[E.g.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0A%2F%2F%20number%0D%0Atype%20LengthPropertyType%20%3D%20String%5B%22length%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20()%20%3D%3E%20number%0D%0Atype%20GetFullYearType%20%3D%20Date%5B%22getFullYear%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20GivenType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20string%0D%0Atype%20DesiredType%20%3D%20GivenType%5B%22prop%22%5D%3B)

```
// number
type LengthPropertyType = String["length"];

// () => number
type GetFullYearType = Date["getFullYear"];

type GivenType = {
    prop: string;
}

// string
type DesiredType = GivenType["prop"];
```